# GCC 7.2 compiles shared library instead of executable

Tags: c, linux, gcc, archlinux

I have a virtual machine with ArchLinux installed. Here when I compile with GCC by running `gcc file.c` it gives me a shared library instead of an executable.

Later I find out that the problem is related only to **GCC 7.2**, in fact, when I compile with **GCC 6.4**, the output file is an executable.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try `gcc -o file.exe file.c`

Comment: What's the output of `alias gcc` ?

Comment: Why do you say it's a shared library? Is the output file called `a.out`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. There's no alias for gcc

Comment: What is the output of `gcc -###` for each version? It may be that your 7.2 compiler was configured to have `-pie`, `-fpie`, etc. as defaults.

Comment: @Oxfist Yea but the file is a shared library. Output of command "file a.out": a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=430094af4d3cf273761bbcd6782e81dcd900c6a0, not stripped

Comment: @Dr.Bass I see pretty much the same output if I run `file a.out` on my machine after compiling with just `gcc source.c`. Have you tried running the binary and check if it works as expected?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i find out that gcc 7.2 has "--enable-default-pie" while gcc 6.4 hasn't

Comment: @Oxfist It works but I don't know why it is a shared library instead of an executable

Comment: More at [Arch now enables PIE and SSP by default in gcc and clang](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6n5tkp/arch_now_enables_pie_and_ssp_by_default_in_gcc/)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So is that the reason? Should I leave it the way it is?

Comment: @Dr.Bass it's worth noting that from the output you posted, which should have been in the question, `file` is not calling your binary a *shared library* but a *shared object*.

Comment: @Oxfist Yea it's thunar that calls it a shared library. In the discussion linked by Mark, it says that PIE is enabled by default for security reasons so I shouldn't change it right?

Comment: @Dr.Bass yes, I'd recommend that you leave those on unless there's a very specific reason not to, and given that you know the implications. In this case it was just that your assumption of the output was wrong, but you really have no problem, from what I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file` utility is just incorrect in calling your program a shared library. It is a position-independent executable (PIE). If you really don't want this, you can specify `-no-pie` at link time, or build a gcc toolchain with `--disable-default-pie`, but in general you shouldn't need to change this.

Comment: Even thunar recognize it as a shared library

Comment: @Dr.Bass: Yes, Thunar is using the exact same library code as `file` to report the file type. It's wrong. This is a known issue.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer that mentioned `file` as you pointed out in the comments, the default `a.out` generated by GCC is *not* a shared library but instead interpreted as a *shared object*  by `file` maybe because of the content of your source code. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects) for more information.